# Python input from cli

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, command-line-interface

I'm making a testing system and want to input test data into the source code from cli (with `os.system("python file_to_test.py { some input data }")`.

But how can I get that data from `file_to_test.py` without changing its code?

I tried to edit `file_to_test.py` with `replace`, but it caused many troubles. So I need to write my `os.system()` command some special way.

It should be something like:

**script.py**

```py
os.system("python file_to_test.py { *some input as my name here* }")
```

**file_to_test.py**

```py
name = input()
print(f'You are { name }')
```

Comment: Why not use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)?

Comment: @srdg I'm a junior and don't know how to push my data into the file with it